# Flutter counter across pages

Tags: flutter, dart, counter

Hey guys I've created a quiz app where i have an extra dart file for every question. Now I want to show a statistic on how many questions were right after the last question. So I want to add _counter++; to every right answer. But how can I show the counter on the last page? So that it gets the data form the pages before?

Answer (score 1):

this is state management issue , you have to look for something like provider to help you with that ..

if not ready just use the old way ..

**pass your counter to every new page through the constructor** to that you will end in the last page with the counter with you.

Comment: Hey thanks so i tried that one but if I have _counter++ on page one and then I want to show $_counter on page 2 it doesn't work because I can't increase the counter across pages.

Comment: yes you can't update its value directly across pages but as I told you you can change it in first page after answering then pass it to second page and use it there and if answer is correct in second page you increase it and so on

Comment: @DaRo if you found this answer useful, kindly accept it :)